# " would require ZIP64 extensions") LargeZipFile: Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

can you please help me sort this error, I am getting an error when I try to write a large file is there any way to fix this error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1696, in _writecheck
    " would require ZIP64 extensions")

LargeZipFile: Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions
```

this is the stacktrace

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-211b07c43cd8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/new_paul.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/new_paul.py", line 106, in <module>
    output_df = gen_stats()

  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/new_paul.py", line 104, in gen_stats
    return merge_main(all_users)

  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/new_paul.py", line 99, in merge_main
    all_users.to_excel('main_with_features_300win.xlsx', index=False)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2127, in to_excel
    engine=engine)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 664, in write
    writer.save()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1952, in save
    return self.book.close()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 306, in close
    self._store_workbook()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 679, in _store_workbook
    xlsx_file.write(os_filename, xml_filename)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1743, in write
    with open(filename, "rb") as src, self.open(zinfo, 'w') as dest:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1470, in open
    return self._open_to_write(zinfo, force_zip64=force_zip64)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1580, in _open_to_write
    self._writecheck(zinfo)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1696, in _writecheck
    " would require ZIP64 extensions")

LargeZipFile: Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions
```

Comment: Means exactly what it says. Standard ZIP format can't store files whose sizes don't fit in a 32-bit integer.

Comment: so how to fix this error please?

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue1446489 for history of why zip64 support was added to the Python standard library only behind a flag to allow it to be explicitly enabled.

Comment: ah okay, does that mean the error cannot be fixed?

Comment: It can certainly be fixed, but doing it in a way that isn't an ugly hack will require changing whatever code actually instantiated the `ZipFile` object. Presumably that's not code you wrote yourself, but code that's in whatever library you're using to write `.xlsx` files.

Comment: ...doing it in a way that _is_ an ugly hack could be something as simple as monkeypatching in a version of the `ZipFile` class for which `allowZip64` is True by default.

Comment: Waitaminute, you _removed_ all the code you were showing, replacing it with a string *The entire code is posted, please help me to fix the error there*?! We ask that questions contain a [mre] -- the shortest possible code that reproduces a problem when run without changes, **within the question itself**.

Comment: (Also, I didn't ask for the whole code; I asked for the whole stack trace).

Comment: I have added the entire stack trace

Answer (score 2):

The flag `allowZip64=True` needs to be passed when initializing a `ZipFile` to allow it to store files larger than 4GB, or to be larger than 4GB itself.

Presumably this is something that needs to be fixed in whatever library you're using that implements `to_excel`. You didn't include that library's identity in your question, so we can't speak to it here.

Comment: It is pandas library I am using to write the large excel file.

Comment: Can you show your whole stack trace, so we can tell which library *pandas* is using? It almost certainly doesn't implement that format itself.

Comment: I have added the entire stacktrace in there

Comment: Okay, that stacktrace tells us the library that pandas is using is called `xlsxwriter`. According to its changelog, at https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#use_zip64, it added a `use_zip64` function in version 0.53. So, you should look at whether pandas has a way to call that function, and if it doesn't, write a patch that makes it do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(data)

with pandas.ExcelWriter(filename,engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    writer.book.use_zip64()
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the analysis from @Charles Duffy you can enable ZIP64 extensions with the xlsxwriter engine like this:

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.book.use_zip64()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in my Python 2.7 script that exports spatial tables from Sql Server to shapefile format and then compress it. Adding 'allowZip64=True' as a parameter worked:

```
zipObj = zipfile.ZipFile(nomZip, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
```